# Header and Background Image Fixed Content and Footer scrolling

Tags: header, scroll, fixed

I have setup a fiddle for my issue [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djnickzremix/8yWrS/5/). What my requirement is? I need the header and the background image to be fixed only. The content should be scrolling, and the footer should also scroll with the content.

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
}

section{
   background: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400);
    height: 400px;
    repeast: no-repeat;
}

footer{
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
}

.clearfix{
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 5px solid #fff;

}
```

HTML

```
<header></header>
<section>
    <div class="clearfix">
        What my requirement is? I want the footer and background image to be position fixed and the footer should be scrolling with the large content.
    </div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: what you mean by "footer should also scroll with the content"? you want sticky footer or footer at the very end?

Comment: hi, I want the footer to be at the very end.

Comment: just remove position: fixed for the footer. it will come after your section

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: fixed center; background-size: cover; this would fix your image

Comment: Okay let me try thanks...

Comment: welcome :) let me know if you fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `overflow:scroll;` to scroll your content

```
.clearfix{
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

You can write your footer inside your div, this will scroll the footer with content